# Angular 6 providedin doesn't work -> StaticInjectorError

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use 'providedin' feature in Angular but receive the error "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DashboardComponent -> DashboardService]:"

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: DashboardModule
})
export class DashboardService {
  getContent() {
    return 'Dashboard Service works!!!';
  }
}
```

Full demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbkjet
Thanks for you effort!

Comment: `providedIn` does NOT automatically inject the service, you need to use the `Injector` to retrieve the service instance if you want to follow that specific route.

Comment: @briosheje, do you mean this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbkjet? If not, could you provide an example?

Comment: no, sorry, I didn't explain properly: if you don't use `providedIn: 'root'`, the service **won't** be singleton. In your case, you can either use `providedIn: 'root'` or, in an easier way, add the `DashboardService` to the `DashboardComponent` providers.

Comment: @briosheje it will be a singleton for every dashboard module instance, which I suppose is the thing he wants. So how to make it tree-shakable on a non root level is the real question, because the `@Injectable` spec does allow other values than `'root'`

Comment: @SIARHEIPAKHUTA this feels like an angular bug. You are working the exact same way as described [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable-providers), which clearly states `In the following excerpt, the @Injectable decorator is used to configure a provider that will be available in any injector that includes the HeroModule.`

Comment: @PierreDuc I can confirm that it's likely a bug: I've tried to replicate the issue in my current project having Angular 6.0.6 and everything is working as intented. Perhaps, in 6.0.0 this feature wasn't yet implemented?

Comment: stackblitz is gone.

Comment: The original stackblitz is gone. But I found a stackblitz example where having an Injectable prodided in a child module works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-providedin-module?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi%2Farticle.service.ts

Answer (score 11):

- 98% of the time, use providedIn = 'root'. It will register the service with the root application injector, will be tree shaken, and will be available to any component that needs it. The tree shaking will ensure the service is only included in the bundles where it is used.
- Use the providers array in a component if the service only needs to be provided in the component and its nested children. (For service isolation at the component level or if you need multiple instances of the service per component.)
- Don't use the providers array in a module (this is old syntax and it no longer recommended)
- Use providedIn='lazymodule' if you want to limit access to a service to a particular lazy loaded module. It will then require an additional module to prevent the circular dependency issue. This provides service isolation at the module level. If any other component in the application outside of this lazy loaded module attempts to reference the service an "out of injector scope" error is generated.

See this for more information on the "additional module": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jigR_jBhDMs&feature=youtu.be

Sample code here: https://github.com/web-dave/provide-in-test

Discussion of the circular dependency issue here: https://github.com/web-dave/provide-in-test/issues/1

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the 'lazymodule' option.  I saw someone else use a "work around" which involved creating an empty module called ServiceModule to avoid the circular dependency.  Seemed to defeat the purpose, since using the providers[ ] at a LazyModule level would produce the same result.

Comment: But it doesn't produce the same result. Using the providers array does not support tree shaking. So any unused code won't be removed. Maybe that is not an issue for your particular project?

Comment: Ah okay I think I see where I went wrong.  I had a broader definition of tree shaking which included lazy loading.  My confusion probably came from the fact that providedIn not only gives us Tree Shaking (removing dead code) but also allows us to lazy load (app wide) singleton services, since the providers array forces us to bring app wide singletons down in our main.js bundle.  In my mind if you are providing a service in a lazy module then you are definitely using it.  So in that case the work around seemed pointless since you won't be providing dead code.

Comment: @DeborahK I'm facing the lazy-loaded-module scenario in which of course im getting the circular deps warning BUT ALSO `no provider` error for my services, which is only being used in the lazy loaded module's component, for what i understand the injector should provide the service just fine.. creating the additional `LazyServiceModule` resolves both the circular deps AND the `no provider`.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at the sample code provided in the "sample code here" link above? Is your code similar?

Answer (score 2):

The [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-providedin?file=src/app/my.service.ts) posted by Stepan Suvorov does not work when using

```
providedIn: AppModule
```

because of a dependency issue, which causes `AppModule` to be unresolved (undefined).

If you add a `console.log(AppModule)` just above the `@Injectable` decorator, the output is `undefined`.

**Note**
You cannot actually see that dependency issue on stackblitz, but you can if you replicate the project on a local angular cli, you'll see the following warnings.

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\app.component.ts -> src\app\my.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.component.ts -> src\app\my.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\my.service.ts -> src\app\app.module.ts -> src\app\app.component.ts -> src\app\my.service.ts

I don't think there is any point in using using `AppModule` in `providedIn`, you may as well use `root`. But if you want your service to only be provided in a child module, this should work like in this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-providedin-module?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi%2Farticle.service.ts)

Here is a [related github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24082)

**Note**: when declaring an injectable service, if you use `providedIn` with a module value, the specified module cannot be a module which declares a component which uses that service (quite a mouthful)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your module imported in the test like this:

```
beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [DashboardModule]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be VSCode automatically adding the service as a provider using intellisense to add the service to the constructor.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-selector',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ CommonModule ]
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [MyRootService], // <-- This creates new instances, remove for static instance
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Finally I have found the solution: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules
Service also should be mentioned in the providers section of module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  exports: [DashboardComponent],
  providers: [DashboardService]
})
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avtubq) has been corrected.
Thank you guys!

Comment: Actually, the link you show are two ways to provide a service. The first way is failing for you for a weird reason. So yes, adding to providers work, but you lose the ability of tree shaking

Comment: @PierreDuc what do you mean "weird reason"? Could you provide an example how to use Service not in the root (application) level and keep ability of tree shaking?
P.S. I have seen your post of original question. So, you think that this is an Angular bug. Maybe, but I can't believe that Google team is failed ))))

Comment: By using `providedIn: DashboardModule` and not adding it to the providers array of the module. But somehow angular is being silly. Are you running the latest version, because this really feels like a bug

Comment: I use version 6.0.4 of Angular

Comment: In demo code is used 6.0.7, it's the latest version

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20159806)

Comment: @MaxVollmer, I added code example and fixed link for demo