# How to use `providedIn` to limit the service to one componet

Tags: angular, angular-services

I create a service, which used with one component, which also has the provide decorator.

```
@Component({
  ....
  providers: [MYSerice]
})
export class MYComponent implements OnDestroy { ... }
```

This service is use by this component alone. So in my service I want to limit the `providedIn` to this component.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MYComponent 
})
export class MYSerice{
```

However this causes a circular dependency, and I cant find a way around it.

This service

1. should only be used by this component
2. be destroyed when the component is destroyed
3. not be used by another component.

Mybe there also is something better than a service for that, but I think this would be the angular way.

What I tried / research:

- Found:
  [Angular 6 providedin doesn't work -> StaticInjectorError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097327/angular-6-providedin-doesnt-work-staticinjectorerror)
  but didn't help my case.
- Tried various combinations but everything beside `providedIn: 'root'`
  threw an error

Thanks for your help

Comment: are you injecting any other service in `MYSerice`, if not the you can remove `@Injectable` decorator

Comment: Yes, I inject other services

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `{ providedIn: ... }` from the `@Injectable` decorator?

Comment: Did you try to use just on [providers] array , and remove it from { providedIn : MyService}  ??  I think this, will work, but also service will be availible in child components...

Comment: Do you have any module enclosing the component in which you are using?

Comment: Thanks for the many questions. Yes I have a module enclosing only the compoennt. I could remove the `providedIn:...` but this would also mean, that is provided in root, since it is the default value. I kinda wanna limit to this component however...

Comment: If you remove the `{ providedIn: ... }` from the `@Injectable` decorator, the code would look like this: `@Injectable()`. That means it would not be provided anywhere, unless you have added the class into a `providers` array *in a module*. Add the class to the providers array of the component you want to use the service, try it then.