# Angular Service for particular NgModule

Tags: angular, service, module, lazy-loading

I'm following the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules) and trying to provide a service (OrderService) to a particular module (OrdersModule). After importing the service to a component (OrderListComponent), I'm getting an error. Could somebody tell me, what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjcbhc) to my stackblitz code.

order.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { OrdersModule } from './orders.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: OrdersModule
})
export class OrderService {
  constructor() {
  }

  ...
}
```

order-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderService } from '../order.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'order-list',
  templateUrl: './order-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './order-list.component.css' ]
})
export class OrderListComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  constructor(private orderService: OrderService) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[OrderListComponent -> OrderService]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[OrderListComponent -> OrderService]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for OrderService!
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Most of the time, use `providedIn = 'root'` inside your service. It will 
   register the
   service with the root application injector, will be tree shaken, and
   will be available to any component that needs it. The tree shaking
   will ensure the service is only included in the bundles where it is
   used.
2. Use the providers array in a component if the service only needs to
   be provided in the component and its nested children.
3. It's not advised to use providers array in a module.

   Use `providedIn='OrdersModule'` if you want to
   limit access to a service to a particular lazy loaded module(OrdersModule). It
   will then require an additional module to prevent the circular
   dependency issue.

   This provides service isolation at the module
   level. If any other component in the application outside of this
   lazy loaded module attempts to reference the service an "out of
   injector scope" error is generated.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51643244/9386929)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25784) on this.

And if you need to provide a service strictly into a lazy-loaded module as you have in your example, then you have two options:

1. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzwmza?file=src/app/orders/orders.module.ts
2. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lazy-load-jxjhfw?file=app%2Fabout%2Fabout.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

You should add `OrderService` into the `providers` array of `OrdersModule`.
Here is a guide how to use `providedIn` and `service`.
https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules